# laravel Notification Undefined index: user_id

Tags: laravel

I going to do massage notification, I already make the notifications steps,
but gives me this error 
when I do  `dd($notifiable);` I found all data

> Undefined index: user_id OR
>   Undefined index: name

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $chating=new chats();
        $chating->chat = $request->input('chat');
        $chating->user_id = Auth::id();
        $chating->employee_id = $request->input('employeeid');
        $chating->save();

        $user_id=$request->input('employeeid');       
        auth()->user()->notify(new SendMassages($user_id));

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

database notifications table coulmn data `{"user_id":5,"name":"Ibrahim"}`

Model

```
    protected $user_id;
    protected $name;
    public function __construct($user_id)
    { 
        $this->user_id = $user_id;
    }
public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['database'];
    }
 public function toDatabase($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'user_id' => $this->user_id,
            'user'=>$notifiable

        ];
    }
```

View:

```
<a href="{{url('chatnow',$notification->data['user_id'])}}">{{ $notification->data['name'] }}</a>
```

Model:

```
class SendMassages extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;
    public $user;
    public $user_id;
    public function __construct($user_id)
    {
        $this->user_id = $user_id;
    }
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['database'];
    }
    public function toDatabase($notifiable)
    {
      // dd($notifiable);
        return [
           'user_id' => $this->user_id,
           'user'=>$notifiable
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: on this auth()->user()->notify(new SendMassages($user_id)); you dont seem to be setting $user_id, maybe above that you need to do $user_id = Auth::id();

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have problem with encapsulation in your code. First you have to make the property of your model into public if you want the quick and not-safe way but if you want the OOP way, You must write setters to do that logic for you.
First and not-safe approach :

```
class YourModel {
    public $user_id;

    .
    .
    .
}
```

The OOP way:

```
Class {
    public function setUserId(int $userId)
    {
        $this->user_id = $userId;
    }

    .
    .
    .
}
```

if you are willing to get the exact answer please copy your controllerclass and model in here.

Comment: Thank you for your comment I tried your solution but I found the same error

Comment: @HimaHima Can you provide your model and your controller code ?

Comment: class SendMassages extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;  
    public $user;
    public $user_id;
    public function __construct($user_id)
    {
        $this->user_id = $user_id;
    }
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['database'];
    }
    public function toDatabase($notifiable)
    {
      // dd($notifiable);
        return [
            'user_id' => $this->user_id,
           'user'=>$notifiable
        ];
    }
}

Comment: public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $chating=new chats();
        $chating->chat = $request->input('chat');
        $chating->user_id = Auth::id();
        $chating->employee_id = $request->input('employeeid');
       
        $chating->save();

        $user_id=$request->input('employeeid');
       

        auth()->user()->notify(new SendMassages($user_id));

       

        return redirect()->back();
    }