# Dears, is there any easy way to creat notifications in laravel "Simple way"

Tags: laravel, notifications

I want to do massage notification in laravel, but really I can't do that.
can anyone give me a simple way to do that.
Thanks in advance.

[See This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57771276/laravel-notification-undefined-index-user-id/57772575#57772575)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel already providing a message notification by default .
Or If you need any clear documentation , 
Please try this .

[Laravel notification message](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/notifications-in-laravel--cms-30499)